# Kendo Grid sorting not working with blank data

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

We are using kendo Grid component for one of our reports. Grid column, sub column sorting is working fine when we have proper data but it fails in case of blank data. Please find the screenshot for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the schema, which sets the type of the column you  are sorting. It works that way.